# Calculating modified Z-score (using median) on R

Tags: r, median, z-score

Does anyone have a formula/code to calculate the modified Z-score (based on median instead of mean) for multiple columns of a dataframe in R?

Example data:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12),
                   y = c(3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9, 19),
                   z = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11))

data %>% 
  mutate(data = (x - median(x))/mad(x))
```

Not sure if this is the correct formula or not.
Basically I want to use this to visualize RNAseq data so I can minimize the effect of outliers on what the plot looks like

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "based on median," because that is ambiguous.  Evidently by "Z-score" you mean a centered and scaled version.  The centering evidently will be performed with the median, but what statistic do you want to use for the scale?  The `R` formula uses the MAD, but there are other reasonable possibilities.

Comment: If you just want to compress your RNA data for visualization purposes, you might consider a plot where you scale the data by the range of the data. That is, divide each observation by $\max -\min$.